# Issue launching app on Heroku: requires different GEMS?

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm trying to push an app to Heroku ... and everything goes well, except that I see an error page when I try to actually view it on Heroku.

On my machine, it works fine though. I followed the basic steps to get a Hello World example going on Heroku and that worked fine on my machine as well as on Heroku ... but my app seems to be having some weird issues.

The push works fine, everything seems to setup correctly, but this is what the logs say:

> 2011-07-09T03:32:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in
>   `block in setup': You have already activated daemons 1.1.0, but your
>   Gemfile requires daemons 1.0.10. Consider using bundle exec.
>   (Gem::LoadError)
>
> ...
>
> 2011-07-09T03:32:35+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) ->
>   GET high-sunrise-670.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service=
>   status=503 bytes= 2011-07-09T03:32:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10
>   (App crashed) -> GET high-sunrise-670.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=
>   queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes= 2011-07-09T03:32:36+00:00
>   heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET
>   high-sunrise-670.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service=
>   status=503 bytes= 2011-07-09T03:40:25+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10
>   (App crashed) -> GET high-sunrise-670.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait=
>   service= status=503 bytes=

I'm very new to this stuff, so I'm sorry if this is a silly question. I don't get why it requires an older daemons version. I checked my Gemfile and nothing required that specifically. I then checked my Gemfile.lock and it says GEM requires it. No idea what that means though (or why Heroku has issues with it ...). Can I change that somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step I'd try to delete Gemfile.lock, run bundle install, then try deploying again.

When you run your application locally, make sure you use bundle exec. This way Gem errors should pop up.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info! I ended up removing one of the items necessary in my Gemfile (mongrel, with a specific version #) and it all worked out. Luckily it doesn't look like I NEED mongrel ... would you suggest that I use it over WEBRick though?

In any case, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Don't use webrick - it's too slow. Most people I know use thin. Works fine for me on Heroku. Add thin to your Gemfile. Use 'thin start' to start rails (assuming you're on rails 3 and have a config.ru file in your root folder). Also, if you're on Heroku Cedar stack, make sure you use thin in your Procfile.